# How to deal with website homepage redirection when opening url connection

Tags: java, redirect, timeout, urlconnection

From the output I understood that the website homepage does refresh and redirects the request to other page that happens ok on a browser but it doesn't on code. so how do I move forward along with that redirection ?

```
try {
            URL url = StringUtils.stringToURL(link);
            URLConnection dbGatewayURL = url.openConnection();
            dbGatewayURL.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    dbGatewayURL.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer responseData = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                responseData.append(line + "\n");
            }
```

The Out put is:

```
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="0;URL=/sites/engbm">
</HEAD>
```

Which raises unexpected end of file exception when I try to `httpUrlConn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to parse the output and look for the `<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH>` tag. It tells the browser that response header equivalents are being included in the content itself. In this case, it's telling the browser to redirect to `/sites/engbm` after `0` seconds. Just to clear up what the `META HTTP-EQUIV` is for: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

> The http-equiv attribute provides an HTTP header for the information/value of the content attribute.
>
> The http-equiv attribute can be used to simulate an HTTP response header.
>
> If the name attribute is set, the http-equiv attribute should not be set.

As for:

> Which raises unexpected end of file exception when I try to `httpUrlConn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");`

This is because [`HEAD` requests have no response body](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a closer look at the http headers. The response code for redirection is 302. And every redirect response comes with a location header. A typical redirect response is as follows

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.org/
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 174
```

read the response code (`HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()`) then read the headers and get the value of `Location` header and make a new request to this URL.

Comment: All HTTP response codes of type 3xx are usually associated to a need to redirect. This includes, for instance, `302 Found`. Not all redirections are implied by 301.

Comment: @Santosh I get response code 200, and header is the same as that one I posted earlier which doesn't contain Location property, please elaborate on the last part of your answer

Comment: The OP's issue is that the redirect is being issued *inside the returned content*, and not as an HTTP response.

Comment: @JonLin If the returned content from the HttpURLConnection indicates a redirection code, wouldn't that have to be triggered by an HTTP response?

Comment: @E_net4 My understanding of the question is that a `200` is being returned, but on browsers the page is getting redirected to somewhere else, but with `URLConnection` it is not, and the content of the requested page contains a `<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="0;URL=/sites/engbm">` which tells the client to redirect. This is in the *content* and not in an HTTP response

Comment: It seems to be a redirection issue under the HTTP entity, rather than the status line. Thanks for the enlightenment on that.